# MongoError: MapReduce internal error :: caused by :: $merge write error: 'on' field '_id' cannot be missing, null, undefined or an array

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB version v4.4

**Sample Input Collection**

```
[{"_id":505059,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":0,"p":1000,"lnkid":505059}},
{"_id":978656,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":385.55,"p":0,"lnkid":978656}},
{"_id":487718,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":0,"p":265300,"lnkid":487718}},
{"_id":1245114,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":20,"p":0,"lnkid":1245114}},
{"_id":928781,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":495,"p":0,"lnkid":928781}},
{"_id":1202556,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":14,"p":0,"lnkid":1202556}},
{"_id":1204437,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":820,"p":0,"lnkid":1204437}},
{"_id":487923,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":0,"p":157,"lnkid":487923}},
{"_id":1259774,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":100,"p":0,"lnkid":1259774}},
{"_id":1260112,"value":{"y":0,"m":0,"cu":50,"p":0,"lnkid":1260112}}]
```

**Sample MapReduce Query**

```
const map = function() {
                emit(this.value.lnkid,{lnkid:this.value.lnkid,crm:this.value.crm||"",cu:this.value.cu||0,p:this.value.p||0});
            }
const reduce = function(k,v) {
                    return v;
                }
const finalize = function(k,v){
                    return v;
                }


collection.mapReduce(map,reduce,
{
    out: {"reduce":"result001"},
    query: "",
    finalize: finalize
},function(err, collection, stats) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

When I Execute this I get the error **MongoError: MapReduce internal error :: caused by :: $merge write error: 'on' field '_id' cannot be missing, null, undefined or an array**

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB documentation,

Starting in MongoDB 4.4, mapReduce no longer supports the deprecated BSON type JavaScript code with scope (BSON type 15) for its functions. **The map function must be either BSON type String (BSON type 2) or BSON type JavaScript (BSON type 13).** To pass constant values which will be accessible in the map function, use the scope parameter.

so I slightly change map function,

```
const map = function() {
                emit(this.value.lnkid+"",{lnkid:this.value.lnkid,crm:this.value.crm||"",cu:this.value.cu||0,p:this.value.p||0});
            }
```

I make sure key always be a string in the emit call.

Now it is working.